# How can I tell if an item is on the screen in Android? getLocalVisibleRect doesn't work in a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I have a GridView full of Square ImageViews. I want to detect which one(s) are currently visible on the screen.  I'm using this code, which doesn't work, but seems like it should:

```
Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
this.container.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
if(imageContainer.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
    Log.d(TAG, "MyPhoto with position " + position + " is visible.");
} else if(!imageView.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
    Log.d(TAG, "MyPhoto with position " + position + " out of sight.");
}
```

1. On load, nothing is said to be visible.
2. As I scroll down, new items come into view, and are said not to be visible.
3. When I reach the bottom, the last item is visible
4. As I scroll up, some new items sporatically become visible

Here is a debug log, with indicators of my activity:

```
11-30 20:27:11.080 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 0 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.080 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 0 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.081 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 0 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.082 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 1 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.083 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 2 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.084 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 3 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.084 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 4 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.085 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 5 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.086 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 6 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.087 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 7 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.093 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 8 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.094 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 9 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.095 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 10 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.095 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 11 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.096 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 12 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.097 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 13 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.097 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 14 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.119 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 0 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:11.119 (Loading) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 0 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:23.525 (Scroll to the bottom) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 15 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:23.526 (Scroll to the bottom) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 16 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:23.526 (Scroll to the bottom) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 17 out of sight.
11-30 20:27:26.019 (Scroll to the bottom) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 18 is visible.
11-30 20:27:29.888 (Scroll up) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 3 is visible.
11-30 20:27:29.888 (Scroll up) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 4 is visible.
11-30 20:27:29.888 (Scroll up) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 5 is visible.
11-30 20:27:30.992 (Scroll up) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 0 is visible.
11-30 20:27:30.992 (Scroll up) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 1 is visible.
11-30 20:27:30.992 (Scroll up) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 2 is visible.
11-30 20:27:35.220 (Scroll back down) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 15 is visible.
11-30 20:27:35.220 (Scroll back down) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 16 is visible.
11-30 20:27:35.220 (Scroll back down) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 17 is visible.
11-30 20:27:36.171 (Scroll back down) D/MyArrayAdaptor: MyPhoto with position 18 is visible.
```

Here is a simple test setup, sans any images, that reproduces the issue in an entirely clean android project.

MainActivity.java

```
package scroll.test.com.scrolltest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyArrayAdaptor arrayAdaptor;
    GridView gv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.list_list_photos);
        arrayAdaptor = new MyArrayAdaptor(this, gv, getData());
        gv.setAdapter(arrayAdaptor);
    }

    private List<MyPhoto> getData() {
        List<MyPhoto> d = new ArrayList<>();
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        d.add(new MyPhoto());
        return d;
    }
}
```

MyArrayAdaptor.java:

```
package scroll.test.com.scrolltest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.List;

public class MyArrayAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<MyPhoto> {

    private final static String TAG = "MyArrayAdaptor";

    private final Context context;
    private final GridView container;

    public MyArrayAdaptor (Context context, GridView container, List<MyPhoto> values) {
        super(context, -1, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.container = container;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.photo, parent, false);
        }

        RelativeLayout imageContainer = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_container);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

        Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
        this.container.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
        if(imageContainer.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "MyPhoto with position " + position + " is visible.");
        } else if(!imageView.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "MyPhoto with position " + position + " out of sight.");
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

SquareImageView.java:

```
package scroll.test.com.scrolltest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SquareImageView extends ImageView
{
    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); //Snap to width
    }
}
```

MyPhoto.java:

```
package scroll.test.com.scrolltest;

public class MyPhoto { }
```

ActivityMain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="scroll.test.com.scrolltest.MainActivity">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/list_list_photos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Photo.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_container">

    <scroll.test.com.scrolltest.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```